# Confusion in Informix when selecting dates with JOIN

Tags: etl, informix, ibm-data-studio

I am trying to run a query in `Informix`, doing a join in a table of logs where we save the record of insertion of the rows.

Notice that the query below brings two results, with different insertion dates:

```
select * from log_cipessoa where cgccpf = 1541247000188
```

Results:

```
 cgccpf         tppessoa    tp_dml  dt_insercao
 -------------  --------    ------  ---------------------
 1541247000188         1    INSERT  2018-03-06 15:05:42.0
 1541247000188         2    INSERT  2018-03-27 09:54:45.0
```

Now, I want to bring the rows that were inserted after the `2018-03-21` day, but while doing the join, informix seems to merge the `dt_insercao` column with the most recent date.

And according to the log above, Informix should only return the second line, where the column `tppessoa` with the value 2 and `dt_insercao` `2018-03-27 09:54:45.0`

```
SELECT pe.cgccpf 
      ,pe.tppessoa
      ,REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(pe.nomepessoa)), '  ', ' ') AS nomepessoa
      ,lg.dt_insercao
FROM CIPESSOA pe
INNER JOIN LOG_CIPESSOA lg
ON lg.cgccpf = pe.cgccpf
WHERE    lg.tp_dml = 'INSERT'
     AND lg.dt_insercao > '2018-03-21 20:09:32' AND lg.dt_insercao <= '2018-03-31 20:00:00'
     and pe.cgccpf = 1541247000188 --FILTER ONLY FOR DEMONSTRATION
```

Results:

```
 cgccpf         tppessoa    nomepessoa      dt_insercao          
 -------------  --------    -----------     ---------------------
 1541247000188         1    XPTO LTDA       2018-03-27 09:54:45.0
 1541247000188         2    XPTO LTDA       2018-03-27 09:54:45.0
```

Comment: Perhaps you have 2 rows in `CIPESSOA` with the same `cgccpf` value (1541247000188)? You can easily check with `select * from cipessoa where cgccpf = 1541247000188 ;` It seems like it, since `pe.tppessoa` shows different values (1 and 2) in the two rows.

Comment: But the date filter should not filter, removing the type of person 1?

Comment: You don't have a filter on type. Why would the filter (which is on a date column in table two, `LOG_CIPESSOA`) filter rows from table one, `CIPESSOA`?

Comment: I think you should show us the table definitions and these 2 rows (all columns) from each table. You may be missing something and the join conditions could be altered. Is there a `tppessoa` column in both tables?

Comment: If there are, you could try `FROM CIPESSOA pe
INNER JOIN LOG_CIPESSOA lg
ON lg.cgccpf = pe.cgccpf AND lg.tppessoa = pe.tppessoa`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but the point is because the oldest line is selected, the date is filtered in WHERE, and is still repeated with the date of the line that should be returned.

Comment: A couple of points.  (1) Which version of Informix on which platform?  (2) What are the rows in the `cipessoa` table that are involved in the join?  If the log table has a record for each record in the operational table, the result you're seeing is the result that should be expected, of course, because you don't filter on the DATETIME column in the `cipessoa` table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, your tip seems to have solved the problem, it makes sense because `tppessoa` differentiates the two rows.